# "Extended" template-based INI file parsing in Python

Tags: python, parsing, asterisk, ini, configparser

I need to parse (and feed to a database) configuration files like this one (actually it is `Asterisk`'s `sip.conf`):

```
[client-template](!,natted-template)
foo=foovalue
moo=moovalue

[client](client-template)
bar=barvalue
```

This syntax means that `client-template` is a template itself (because of `!` in parentheses) based on `natted-template` (defined elsewhere). And `client` is an object definition, based on `client-template`.

I could use `ConfigParser`, but it looks like I need something more powerful or customized?

Answer (score 0):

Well, now I've tried `pyparsing`:

```
import pyparsing as pp

filename = 'client.conf'

nametag = pp.Word(pp.alphanums + "-_")

variable = pp.Word(pp.alphanums)
value = pp.Word(pp.alphanums + "=")

vardef = pp.Group(variable('variable') + pp.Literal("=").suppress() + value('value'))
vardefs = pp.Group(pp.ZeroOrMore(vardef))('vardefs')

section = pp.Group(pp.Literal("[").suppress() \
        + nametag('objectname') \
        + pp.Literal("]").suppress() \
        + pp.Optional(
                pp.Literal("(").suppress() \
                + pp.Optional("!")('istemplate')
                + pp.ZeroOrMore(pp.Optional(",").suppress() + nametag)('parenttemplates') \
                + pp.Literal(")").suppress()
            ) \
        + vardefs)

section = section + pp.Optional(pp.SkipTo(section)).suppress()

section_group = pp.Group(section + pp.ZeroOrMore(section))('sections')

config = (pp.SkipTo(section_group).suppress() \
        + section_group)


# res = config.parseString(open(filename).read())
```

This is a part of a solution (and this is comments unaware so far), but I can proceed with it.

Please, if there is more elegant solution, let me know.